# Spring security 3.1 sitemesh not decorating page

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, sitemesh

I am in the middle of the process of upgrading a project to spring 3.2 and spring security 3.1 . site mesh is in the 2.4.2 version. the behavior is the next. 
if i write the next url `http://localhost:8081/erp-web/`  the server gives me the only the login page.[image: page not decorated by sitemesh]

but if i write the next url `http://localhost:8081/erp-web/login.mavi` the server gives me the  login page properly decorated. like this [image: page properly decorated.]

this is my security conf

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/decorators/**" access="permitAll"/>
<security:intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />      
<security:intercept-url pattern="/login.do" access="permitAll" />

<security:form-login login-page="/login.do"
    default-target-url="/home.do" authentication-failure-url="/login.do?login_error=1" />
<security:logout logout-success-url="/logout.do" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>
```

and in the web.xml

```
<!-- SECURITY -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- SITEMESH -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

this is the view resolver.

```
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
            p:viewClass="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"
            p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />
```

cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. The solution was easy. i just added to my `decorators.xml` this line

```
<pattern>/</pattern>
```

and now it looks like this.

```
<decorator name="login" page="login.jsp">
    <pattern>/</pattern>
    <pattern>/login.do</pattern>
    <pattern>/spring_security_login</pattern>
</decorator>
```